# issue with get url from menu id

Tags: joomla

I have the following code for joomla 2.5 ....

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$id = 474;
$link = JRoute::_($menu->getItem($id)->link);

?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
var $link = $('<a>',{
    class: 'all-news-link',
    href: <?php echo json_encode( $link ); ?>
});
$('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').append($link);
});

</script>
```

But it is not getting menu id 474 but 468 that is home page id. My SEF is also not turned on.

Comment: You should be able to just do this: `$link = JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=474');`

Comment: not working like it also makes a link to the homepage?

Comment: Oops it's working and showing 474 id but don't go to that id page is going where.....

Comment: output should be this `option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=474` but result is `option=com_content&amp;view=featured&amp;Itemid=474` There is difference in & and &amp; only...

Comment: Its working now I just removed JRoute::_(). Thanks David

Comment: Cool. I think that happens when it gets routed twice. There is a plugin in Joomla that also handles some routing automatically, which can be problematic like this.

Comment: Could you post your answer please, what you want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just do this:

```
$link = 'index.php?Itemid=474';
```

Assuming that the location that you print it on the page is picked up by the system plugin that routes output all will be well.

If that is actually what makes it to the page, then you would want to route it manually:

$link = JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=474');

The router will handle getting the link for you.